# Beamer's slide without footer

Tags: beamer, header-footer

Goood morning. I'd like to make a slide of title without footer and it's mentioned in the others slides. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Welcome to tex.se. What exactly is your question?

Comment: thankx :) .My questionis :how to delete a footeline from the first slide in a beamer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the desired result you have two options:

1. Use the `plain` option for the frame; this will suppress both the headline and the footline for that frame.
2. Locally redefine the `footline` template to be empty. This will kill the footline but keeping the headline.

The following example shows both possibilities and a "regular" frame with both elements for comparison:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
test frame without headline and footline
\end{frame}

\begingroup
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\begin{frame}
test frame without footline but with headline
\end{frame}
\endgroup

\begin{frame}
test frame with footline and headline
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]